# execution of paragraph text in background even if browser tab change in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, background

I am working on a react project where i am calling an api and in response i am getting some data which i am storing in state. For showing data, i am mapping that state and in that state value is a long text which i am showing through Typewriter animation

```
<Typewriter
text={
data.result
delay={5}
onAnimationComplete={(value) =>handleAnimationComplete(value)
}
/>
```

when i call the api then fully code is working and data is being animated as i required. but when i change the tab then animation get paused and when i go back to that tab then it continues from that position.

but i want continuous execution of that data in background even if tab is changed.

Tried many solution but not working as per my requirement. any help would be appreciated